# How is airspeed measured on supersonic aircraft?

Tags: airspeed, supersonic, sensors, pitot-static

Behind the shock wave air is subsonic, would that not cause an issue with the pitot tubes or any other sensor?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160413/how-does-a-supersonic-flight-speedometer-work